# How to use spawn child_process in Meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, npm, angular-meteor

I'm creating a Meteor Angular app.

I want to import Node's, child process like this:

```
var spawn = Npm.require('child_process').spawn;
```

When I try this, Meteor responds that Npm is not defined. I know this is the old way of using npm packages. What is the current way to use this?

I believe I need to use import but don't know in what form to do so

I tried `import spawn from 'child_process'` to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me this works (server/main.js)

```
import {spawn} from 'child_process';
console.log(spawn); // I20160524-22:04:42.927(2)? [Function]
```

what's your output?
and also this should work

```
import childProcess from 'child_process';
console.log(childProcess.spawn)
```